# ArcGIS Pro 2.5 - Calculate sum of a field in Arcade

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcade

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.5 and I am trying to calculate the sum of a field in Arcade. I used

```
Sum($layer, "Population")
```

However when verifying I get the message that "Object Not Found $layer". I am wondering if the global $layer is available in ArcGIS Pro 2.5?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Field Calculate Profile

I am assuming that you are using the **Field Calculator** based on your question.

`$layer` is certainly present in Pro 2.5, and is included in the Field Calculate profile of Arcade. The code you give in your post should work just fine, as pictured below. I used the Arcade Playground to test it.

According to [the Esri docs](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/guide/profiles/#field-calculate), the current Field Calculate profile has been in place since Arcade v 1.5, which would have been back in Pro 2.3, so I don't think the Pro version is causing your problem.

[image: field sum in arcade]

## Other Profiles

It's also possible you're not using the **Field Calculator**, but are trying to sum a field for use in another Arcade profile, such as generating popup content, symbology, or labels. In some cases, the `$layer` global is not accessible. You should refer to the other profiles in the doc link above to see which globals are available to your particular situation.

Comment: No, it seems it is not available in Pro 2.5.2. I tested it on 3 different systems. What you are showing is the Arcade Playground. It is available there [probably as part of AGO]. I am using field Calculator in ArcGIS Pro and it sends an error message that the $layer is not available.

Comment: That's very strange. I'm using 2.5.2 myself and it works just fine, and I have tested it there as well. What kind of data source are you using?

Comment: Thank you Josh for your response; I edited my question and added a screenshot of my Field Calculator. I updated Arc Pro to 2.6 as well. Can you show a screenshot of the field calculator on your machine and validate it? This is very strange it is not working here!